# SSIS OLEDB source error - Opening a rowset for SQL Server View failed

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis, bids, sql-view

We have an SSIS package where we have used SQL server view as a data source by selecting data access mode as Table or view. The package has been scheduled to run daily using SQL Server Job. Most of the time the job gets executed without any issue, but once in a while, we are getting the below-given error.

> Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility  Version 10.50.6560.0
>   for 32-bit  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2010. All rights
>   reserved.     Started:  6:08:03 AM   Error: 2019-02-06 06:10:56.02
>   Code: 0xC0202009      Source: Load  Package OLE DB Source [1]
>   Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has
>   occurred.  Error code: 0x80004005.   End Error  Error: 2019-02-06
>   06:10:56.40      Code: 0xC02020E8    Source: Load  Package OLE DB
>   Source [1]     **Description: Opening a rowset for "[ss].[someView]"
>   failed.  Check that the object exists in the database**.   End Error 
>   Error: 2019-02-06 06:10:56.80     Code: 0xC004701A      Source: Load 
>   Package SSIS.Pipeline     Description: component "OLE DB Source" (1)
>   failed the pre-execute phase and returned error code 0xC02020E8.

The view does exist in the database. What could be the root cause of this issue?

Comment: Is it possible that there's a process elsewhere in your environment that periodically drops and recreates that `VIEW`?

Comment: No, and even that view has not been changed since last year.

Comment: Is the view on the same server or on another server?

Comment: It's on the same server

Comment: Try using an `SQL Command` as source and use a fully qualified view name: `SELECT * FROM [database].[ss].[someView]`

Comment: Try setting `DelayValidation` to "true" if it is not already.